# remove table tags but not p tags with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, django, regex, beautifulsoup

I have problem with delete table in text in django object. Sometimes I have `<p>` tags inside `<table>`. How to avoid delete p tags but delete table tags. For now I am deleting table and it is ok when p tag is outside of table. To do all this things I am using BeautifulSoup.

```
for obj in article:
    soup_en = BeautifulSoup(obj.text_en, features="html5lib")
    if soup_en.find_all('table'):
        for i in soup_en.select('table'):
            i.decompose()
    obj.text_en = str(soup_en).replace(r'\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n','').replace(r'\r\n', '\n').replace('#####444#####', '').replace('#####555#####', '')
    obj.save()
```

html code

```
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">\r\n
    <TBODY>\r\n
        <TR>\r\n
            <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: "><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=16></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: " bgColor=#cccccc><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=1></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ">
                <P class=flowtextblack><STRONG>Information:</STRONG>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: It will be easier if you show the html code that you try to parse.

Comment: This looks oddly similar to your previous question, and you still haven't gotten back to us in that question

Comment: @MartinMårtensson pls check html code

Comment: @Chase thanks a lot for previous answer, but this one is a different.

Comment: do you want to get rid of everything which is related to table? tbody, tr, td and so on?

Comment: @MartinMårtensson yes, I need only p tag and his conent

Comment: if you just need the p tags within, why don't you *select* those instead of selecting the table...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table like so-

```html
<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">\r\n
    <TBODY>\r\n
        <TR>\r\n
            <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: "><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=16></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: " bgColor=#cccccc><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=1></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ">
                <P class=flowtextblack><STRONG>Information:</STRONG>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>
```

And you want the `p` tags within it. Please just select the `p` tags instead of selecting the `table`. I've already said this in my previous answer, but trying to replace stuff from an element directly (instead of the `.text` of it) is a ridiculously bad idea.

On top of that, if you aim to replace things inside an element just to get another element inside......that just defeats the entire purpose of an HTML parser. Why not just select that element in the first place..?

To understand how to select any element you want with maximal accuracy and specifics. Please get familiar with [css selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors).

Now, let's get to the actual answer-

```py
html = """<HTML><BODY><TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">\r\n
    <TBODY>\r\n
        <TR>\r\n
            <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: "><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=16></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: " bgColor=#cccccc><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=1></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ">
                <P class=flowtextblack><STRONG>Information:</STRONG>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"""
```

You can use this css selector - `table > tbody > tr > td > p` to get all the `p` tags within the `td` tags of the table. To get all elements that match a css selector, you use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
p_elems = soup.select('table > tbody > tr > td > p')

for p_elem in p_elems:
    print(p_elem.text)
```

Output-

> Information:Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

If you *do not* want to use css selectors. Fortunately, this specific problem is very easy without them as well. All you need, is to get the `table` element first and then `.find` the `p` elements within it.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
table = soup.find('table')
p_elems = table.find_all('p')

for p_elem in p_elems:
    print(p_elem.text)
```

Output-

> Information:Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the content of the `p`'s which are inside of a `table` then you just have to write this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup_en = BeautifulSoup(obj.text_en, 'lxml')
tds = soup.find_all('td')
ps = []
for td in tds:
    p = td.find('p')
    if p != None:
        ps.append(p)

print(ps)
```

And now you have a list of all the `p`'s inside of tables.

Hope if was helpfull :)

Comment: unfortunately, this will find *all* `p` tags within the document, not just the ones within the `table` :)

Comment: you can change the `td` with `table` if that is better, and of course write `ps[0].text` to get the actual content. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `.findChildren()`, `.find_parent()` and `.unwrap()` to remove all elements around the `<p>` tag inside `<table>` tag:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<TABLE border=0 cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 width="100%">\r\n
    <TBODY>\r\n
        <TR>\r\n
            <TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: "><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=16></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: " bgColor=#cccccc><IMG src="http://www.example.com/nix.gif" width=416 height=1></TD></TR>\r\n<TR>\r\n<TD style="BORDER-BOTTOM-COLOR: ; BORDER-TOP-COLOR: ; BORDER-RIGHT-COLOR: ; BORDER-LEFT-COLOR: ">
                <P class=flowtextblack><STRONG>Information:</STRONG>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </P>
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </TBODY>
</TABLE>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for table in soup.select('table:has(p)'):               # <-- select all <table>s that have <p> tag
    for t in table.findChildren():                      # <-- find all children tags of this table
        if t.name != 'p' and not t.find_parent('p'):    # <-- if tag is not <p> and not inside <p> tag then unwrap() it
            t.unwrap()
    table.unwrap()                                      # <-- unwrap() the top <table> tag

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<p class="flowtextblack"><strong>Information:</strong>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum </p>
```